# Paypal sandbox account balance doesn't change

Tags: php, paypal-sandbox

I am using Paypal Express checkout ... When the user clicks "checkout with paypal" in mysite I send a SetExpressCheckout to paypal with the required information to get the token and redirect him to this url:
https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=RESPONSE_TOKEN&useraction=commit

I am sending "&useraction=commit" along with the request to pay directly without coming back to my site and send another request "DoExpressCheckout"

It works great I click on "checkout with paypal" button I redirected to paypal sandbox and enter my test account email and password .. review my shipping address information and click "Pay Now" and I am redirected back to the returnUrl I specified earlier.. But after that when I login to my test account my balance stays the same! Am I missing something? Do I have to make a DoExpressCheckout Request after the user is redirected back to my site ?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. When sending "&useraction=commit" along with the request, Paypal tells the user that he will pay, but after Paypal returns to my site I have to make a DoExpressCheckout request to complete the transaction.